# Duplicate a Row Based on a Condition SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-table

I have a table that looks like this

```
+-------+------+------+----------+ 
| Index |  F1  |  F2  | Multiply | 
+-------+------+------+----------+
|  0    |  LG  |  SC  |     1    |
|  1    |  WE  |  CC  |     1    |
|  2    |  TY  |  PL  |     2    |
+-------+------+------+----------+
```

And I want to multiply the 'Multiply' Column by 2 to determine how many rows to add to the result. With the example above, I want my SQL Query to return:

```
+------+-----+-----+
|Index | F1  | F2  |
+------+-----+-----+
|  0   |  LG | SC  | 
|  0   |  LG | SC  |
|  1   |  WE | CC  |
|  1   |  WE | CC  |
|  2   |  TY | PL  |
|  2   |  TY | PL  |
|  2   |  TY | PL  |
|  2   |  TY | PL  |
+------+-----+-----+
```

I don't have much experience writing SQL queries so help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Because 2 x 1 = 2?

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
with myTable as (
    select * from (values 
        (0,'LG','SC',1)
        ,(1,'WE','CC',1)
        ,(2,'TY','PL',2)
    ) t ([Index], F1, F2, Mutiply)
)
select
    [Index], F1, F2
from
    myTable m
    join master.dbo.spt_values v on m.Mutiply * 2 > v.number
where
    Type = 'P'
```

Edit: adding some description

By writing a query like

```
select * from table 
cross join (values (1),(2)) t(n)
```

we can double rows in the table. And `cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) t(n)` will quadruple the rows. In this case row multiplication will depend on column `Multiply`. So we need to multiply by 2 value of column `Multiply` and join with table with sequence of numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7...) where number is less than calculated value. For example, for `Multiply = 2`, join condition will be 4 numbers (0, 1, 2, 3) which are less than 2*2. And those 4 numbers will quadruple initial row.

`master.dbo.spt_values` is only used to get numbers sequence. Sequence can be generated at runtime or another table with numbers sequence can be used

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to this answer. It will be of great help.

Comment: Added a description as best as I could :) Let me know if it is understandable

Comment: @uzi  Perfect :)

Comment: Excellent .. But why did you keep a condition `> v.number` .didn't get here

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use recursive CTE:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
    (0, 'LG', 'SC', 1),
    (1, 'WE', 'CC', 1),
    (2, 'TY', 'PL', 2)
    ) as t([Index], F1, F2, Multiply)
), final AS (
    SELECT  [Index], 
            F1, 
            F2, 
            Multiply*2 as Multiply 
    FROM cte  -- At first we get basic recordset with x2 in Multiply
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  [Index], 
            F1, 
            F2, 
            Multiply-1
    FROM final  -- On each iteration we select columns we need and
    WHERE Multiply-1 > 0   -- use Multiply as counter
)

SELECT  [Index], 
        F1, 
        F2
FROM final
ORDER by [Index]
```

Output:

```
Index       F1   F2
----------- ---- ----
0           LG   SC
0           LG   SC
1           WE   CC
1           WE   CC
2           TY   PL
2           TY   PL
2           TY   PL
2           TY   PL

(8 rows affected)
```