# How to create duplicate detail sections based on field entry?

Tags: crystal-reports, duplicates

I'm setting up a report in Crystal Reports that generates product labels based on information pulled from a Part Order in a database. I want the report to generate the number of labels for each part in accordance with the quantity for each part. While many people try to remove duplicates, I would like to create a duplicate of each label depending on the value of the quantity field.

I currently have each label in separate detail sections with no groups of any kind. There are 10 on a page, with 2 columns of five so they fit standard Avery labels. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: do it over your dataset (command) over sql ... just a matter of using cross join or join to explode your data according to the quantity

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea what the syntax for that would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duplicate your query with UNION between them.

Comment: What would the syntax for this look like? Wouldn't it create duplicate queries for every label instead of just the ones with quantities greater than one?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand correctly. Yeah you can't use UNION then. You need a cross join like maSTAShuFu told you.
See this link for syntax help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48557840/10191493

Comment: Perfect, that looks like exactly what I need. Thanks TheOne__!

Comment: No problem. Mark the anwser as useful, by clicking on the top arrow please , so we can help more people :)